# Dynamically resizing form - simple db design?

Tags: php, mysql, forms

So I have three fields in my form: User info, Host Name info, and Additional Info. The Host Name info is a dynamic field meaning that the user could add more fields for that section. One of my solutions is to do a for loop in the php POST page and submit that information based on how many host names there are. Is there a better way than this? My end goal is wanting to extract this info from the MySQL db and display it based of each form submission. I just want to display the users information ONCE and then all the host names associated with that user.

Example:

Let's say we already had a couple of requests submitted from the form. Then the db will now look like this (leaving out addinfo):

The host name is the dynamic field in the form.

### First-----Last-----HostName

John-----Doe-----www.test1.com

John-----Doe------www.test2.com

John-----Doe-----www.test3.com

Ally-----Parker-----www.hello1.com

Ally-----Parker-----www.hello2.com

John-----Doe-----www.tired1.com

John-----Doe-----www.tired2.com

How can I pull data so that it will just pull each request alone (account for other users)?

**End Goal example:**

Request 1: 
First: John, Last: Doe, HostNames: www.test1.com, www.test2.com, www.test3.com
Request 2: 
First: Ally, Last: Parker, HostNames: www.hello1.com, www.hello2.com
Request3:
First John, Last Doe, HostNames: www.tired1.com, www.tired2.com

Comment: Do you have some code? Or simply just want from us to code it for you?

Comment: sorry I'm new. I'll add some code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your DB design is fundamentally wrong, ideally you should split this into two tables:

Table 1: User ID, First name, Last name, Additional Info...where each user is stored once.

Table 2: User ID, Host Name, where the combination of user ID and host name is stored.

You can then fetch the IDs from table 1 and use that to fetch host name from table 2 in two queries.

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was thinking about but was confused of the User ID as being the primary key. How would I link those together in two separate tables? I guess table1's user id will autoincrement but what about table2 (since there are multiple fields)?

Comment: Table 1's user ID is simply the primary key set to auto increment, table 2's user ID is a simple integer set as a foreign key linking to table 1's user ID. Table 2's user ID doesn't have any unique constraints since it can have multiple entries for the same user ID. This is a one-to-many relation between user and hosts basically.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you so much!!